# Interface Builder vs. What's Displayed on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

Hello and thanks for giving this question a gander.

It seems that PNG files that I drag/drop into IB do not display in the same manner that they are shown in the iPhone simulator. What gives? For example, if I want to drop in a PNG with rounded corners, IB shows hard rectangular corners but when I build to the simulator, I see the rounded edges.

I don't understand the purpose of IB for UI if I can't accurately reflect what will be shown for that view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you verify that the PNG files are saved with a pixel density of 72dpi?  Also, what type of UI element are you using? (UIButton, UIImageView, etc).  It would help if you could post a sample image.